# JavaFX String copied to the clipboard is truncated starting with null character '\u0000'

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard

I have a String with null characters. When I copy it to clipboard and paste to notepad, I receive only the beginning of the line, before null character. Is it a JavaFX bug?

```
String data = "begginning\u0000ending";
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString(data);
Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
// Output will be "beginning"
```

Comment: That sounds like a restriction of whatever clipboard system you're putting it in. A lot of those use C APIs under the hood and a C string can't contain a null character, because null is used as a terminator. Indeed: [Windows can't have null characters in the clipboard at all](https://superuser.com/questions/946533/is-there-any-way-to-copy-null-bytes-ascii-0x00-to-the-clipboard-on-windows).

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, you comment looks more like an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is likely a restriction of whatever clipboard system you're putting it in. A lot of those use C APIs under the hood and a C string can't contain a null character, because null is used as a terminator.

And indeed: [Windows can't have null characters in the clipboard at all](https://superuser.com/questions/946533/is-there-any-way-to-copy-null-bytes-ascii-0x00-to-the-clipboard-on-windows), and I suspect it's not alone in having this restriction.

So in this case the result you got is the best that the JavaFX Clipboard API can hope to do.